FireFox Fails to Open from Favorites, but does open on the command line
I am running Ubuntu 22.04 and firefox 133.0 from snap. When I launch firefox from the command line I get these warnings but it does launch. When I select new window from the firefox icon in Favorites, the hour glass spins and spins and then quits with no new firefox window appearing. What should I do to get a new firefox window when I click on the Favorites icon?
Gtk-Message: 08:53:36.252: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
[233730, Main Thread] WARNING: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/5361/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.: 'glib warning', file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:201

(firefox:233730): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:53:36.295: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/5361/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 08:53:36.295: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[233730, Main Thread] WARNING: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/5361/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.: 'glib warning', file /build/firefox/parts/firefox/build/toolkit/xre/nsSigHandlers.cpp:201

(firefox:233730): Gtk-WARNING **: 08:53:36.296: GTK+ module /snap/firefox/5361/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 08:53:36.296: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"


Check Task Manager some other process listing tool to see if Firefox is already running.  If it is kill that process and try to start agin.

Firefox is running. I have a window open with firefox and a few tabs. I want to open another firefox window. When I run ps aux | grep firefox I get 26 separate processes. I have 13 tabs open in one window and 2 tabs in another firefox window.

Can you open a new tab vs a new window?

Yes, no problem. I can also move the tab to a new window, which is what I have been doing, then moving that new window to another screen/desktop to work with it. But it is annoying to go through that process when I just want to go to a new desktop/screen and open a new firefox window.

When you completely close all Firefox Windows/Tabs etc and do another ps aux | grep firefox is the output null?

I get one entry, which I think is the search entry because if I do a pkill firefox and then the ps aux..., I get the same response:
ps aux | grep firefox returned
mark      251636  0.0  0.0   9080  2400 pts/6    S+   15:31   0:00 grep --color=auto firefox
Also, I could not start a firefox window by clicking on the Favorites entry (hour glass spinner just spun, then died), I had to resort to the CLI.

kill the last firefox entry by  kill <pid> then do another ps aux Once none exist in the list try starting from the icon.

The last firefox entry is the ps aux search. If I do ps aux |grep [f]irefox, nothing appears. Grep is finding itself in the search. And, yes, with all firefoxes dead, the Favorites button works again. Do I have to periodically kill all the firefox windows to get a new one? Probably a better process search is pgrep firefox. It does not report itself.

The Issue here was that one of the Firefox processes drew a Window that was counted as Open, but the Window was "invisible".  Every time you clicked on a new window, Firefox was sending the handle ID for the invisible window that you couldn't use because you couldn't see it. This happens on rare occassions even in that "other" OS that everyone uses.  Killing all the processes related to the phantom window causes the "invisible" window to be destroyed and recreated upon reopening.

Snaps have a configuration menu under 'Apps' under 'Settings' app. So go to 'Settings' - 'Apps' - 'Firefox' and try experimenting with the permission settings.

Ubuntu Firefox is snap based, it's not very good for daily driving, I suggest to remove Firefox snap and install deb installer instead for more stability (NOTE: Please make sure you sync/backup your data before doing this):
#!/bin/sh
sudo apt install wget
sudo umount /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/snapd/
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd gnome-software-plugin-snap
sudo rm -fr ~/snap
sudo apt-mark hold snapd
sudo install -d -m 0755 /etc/apt/keyrings
wget -q https://packages.mozilla.org/apt/repo-signing-key.gpg -O- | sudo tee /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc > /dev/null
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.mozilla.org.asc] https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozilla.list > /dev/null
echo '
Package: *
Pin: origin packages.mozilla.org
Pin-Priority: 1000
' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla
sudo apt update && sudo apt install firefox

